# How to unlist a list of dgematrices in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of various size dgematrices that I am trying to unlist.

I have tried the unlist function and varied its arguments. I have tried stack and other peoples suggestions, for some reason nothing works. Here is the output:

```
[[166]]
1 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1]
[1,] 81.62873

[[167]]
3 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
         [,1]
[1,] 89.76647
[2,] 81.53676
[3,] 69.37639
```

nothing changes in the output. it returns a list again. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Maybe `list2env`?

Comment: Thanks, but it returns error 'names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x'